# Shopify - host multiple themes at the same time

Tags: url, themes, liquid, shopify

So, I'm selling some products on shopify. Let's say coffee.

I'm working with a new group that wants to sell my coffee, have a separate brand, have a branded website. Is there an easy way to do this with a single shopify account?

I added this to my page template

```
{% if page.title == "Cards Coffee" %}
    {% layout "cardscoffee" %}
{% endif %}
```

And I could see how I could use this to create a separately themed page. But his will only work if I'm linking directly to a sub page. I'm going to setup a separate DNS name for this new brand. Is there any way to get the requested url?

(page.url returns the main configured url, not what was actually requested).

Is there another approach I should be taking entirely (besides forking out an extra subscription?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of suggestions:

1. Use Javascript to grab the domain and add it as a CSS class on your  element. Then add CSS rules dependent on that class that have the different branding.
2. If the new group already has a site you might consider giving them a plugin they can embed that uses the [Shopify Javascript API](http://wiki.shopify.com/Ajax_API) to list products (the API now supports JSONP). If you go down this path, take a look at [this article](http://wiki.shopify.com/Adding_to_the_Cart_from_a_remote_website) on the wiki that discusses how to remotely add to the cart.

Comment: Thanks for your javascript suggestion. That will probably work. I need to go figure out the code, but this will probably lead to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way of doing the same.

- Start by creating a new layout. Let's say it's called `cardscoffee.liquid`
- Create a new alternative `page.liquid`. Let's call it `page.cardscoffee.liquid`
- Make the new `page.liquid` just like the original one, except add `{% layout 'cardscoffee' %}` to the top.

Now you will see that the Shopify Admin will give you a way of selecting which liquid file to use when you are editing a page.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem when people come to the front page.